# Run script in runlevel 1

Tags: linux, runlevel

I'm trying to run a script in runlevel 1 out of `/etc/inittab`. The script I want to run looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
  #do something
  sleep 1
  #do something
  sleep 1
done
```

The `inittab` line looks like this: `d666:123456:respawn:/root/script_to_run.sh`

In runlevel 2-6 everything works fine. When I change into runlevel 1 (`init 1`) the script gets stopped and isn't executed anymore.

Also I'm trying to handle a script to be called right before runlevel 0 is entered. I tried this line in `inittab`: `d667:0:wait:/root/script_to_run_right_before_runlevel_0.sh`

Comment: Which `init` system, and/or which Linux distribution? What other runlevel 1 entries are in your `/etc/inittab`?

Comment: It's `Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 debarm` in an embedded system. One more entry for runlevel 1 is `l1:1:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian documentation isn't explicit, `init(8)` cautions only that runlevels S,0,1,6 are reserved, and also:

> On a Debian system, entering runlevel 1 causes all processes to be killed except for kernel threads and the script that does the killing and other processes in its session. As a consequence of this, it isn’t safe to return from runlevel 1 to a multi-user runlevel: daemons that were started in runlevel S and are needed for normal operation are no longer running. The system should be rebooted.

Run level 1 in `/etc/inittab` is:

```
l1:1:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 1
```

`/etc/init.d/rc 1` will call `/etc/rc1.d/S*` including `S01killprocs` which kills most things it can find, and `S21single`, which performs "`exec init -t1 S`", to switch to single-user mode, so runlevel 1 is very short-lived. Single-user mode "S" in `/etc/inittab` is:

```
~~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

which means that `init` will simply wait until wait until `sulogin` returns before doing anything else.

In short, runlevels "1" and "S" are "hands-off" in Debian (and probably most other unixen too).

If you put your inittab entry above the system "S" entry, then `init` respawning and the `S01killprocs` script will fight it out for a while (you may not get to observe that without a running syslog), which is probably racy, and probably won't do what you want.

You *may* be able to some of what you need by either or both of  modifying the startup scripts, and implementing an `/etc/initscipt` to monitor and log the various actions of `init`. These are a *really* good way to hose a working system, so I suggest experimenting in a vm first ;-).

I think your other options, neither of which seem very appealing, are to try a different `init`, or see if you can do what you want via a kernel thread.